# Is there a phrase for high start up cost?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Currently I restarted lifting (weights) after a 2 month hiatus to get stronger. Back when I was lifting almost daily, like 5 times a week, there was no soreness in my arms. But when I started, I remember there was a lot of soreness and you just adapt. Is there a phrase or even a single word that describes how it starts off hard, then it only gets easier? I realize that you can "adapt" to the situation, but that is not the phrase/word I am looking for. The best analogy I come up with is in chemistry, where some things have a high activation energy but then the chart gets lower. The phrase does not have to relate to weights/lifting/fitness.

Comment: This seems more a question for the Stack Exchange - *Sports* site.

Comment: I'll flag it, so that a moderator can see.

Comment: Are you actually asking about sports in particular (and if so, what the phenomenon is called in that particular case would be better on another site), or for a general term -- in which case *high start up cost* would appear to fit the bill?

Comment: I am looking for a general term. I am just looking for a phrase that just means it gets better as it goes on and use lifting in my example and also chemistry i guess. After thinking about it, perhaps growing pains fits the bill but idk maybe I'm just searching for other examples and seeing if they fit better or if I like it better.

Comment: I was going to suggest  acclimate but that isn't it; it's too passive.  My example would be those tender fingers one gets when initially picking up a guitar.  It's that initial floundering/pain of a new activity which subsides after time.

Comment: @user116032 Yup that is exactly what I am looking for. Except either in a single word or phrase.

Comment: It's not a perfect fit, but it's similar to _learning curve_.

Comment: What @Barmar said, *steep learning curve*.

Comment: It won’t work in the chemistry example, but @user116032 ‘s mention of sore fingers and learning guitar made me think of Ringo’s “You got to [**pay your dues**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+dues) if you want to [play] the blues (without hurting your fingers) ...And you know it don't come easy.”

Comment: You took a two-month hiatus to get stronger?

Answer (score 2):

In business, one might call these high startup costs a **barrier to entry**, which is defined by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barriers_to_entry) as "an obstacle that makes it difficult to enter a given market".

Answer (score 1):

**[growing pains:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/growing-pains?q=growing%20pains)** The difficulties experienced in the early stages of an enterprise.